# Ubuntu 12.04 Can't Play DVDs with Libdvdcss installed

Tags: 12.04, vlc, dvd, multimedia, media

I've installed VLC, libdvdread4, libdvdcss, Medibuntu and Ubuntu restricted extras AND ran this line of code...

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

...on my Ubuntu 12.04 but whenever I start a DVD, whether it be with or without DVD menus the VLC player does not play. When I run it without a DVD menu, I'm returned with this...

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not read -1/4 blocks at 0x01.
```

If I attempt to change the region set using `regionset` to 1 then I am returned with this...

```
ERROR: Region code could not be set!
```

I've tried running the DVD on Gnome MPlayer to no avail. Help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing win32codecs? i had the same problem on 13.04, but now i solved it. Try this...

```
$ sudo apt-get install win32codecs
```

for 32 bit systems, or maybe...

```
$ sudo apt-get install win64codecs
```

for 64 bit